# Comparing NOW() with a list of dates in Excel to return current period?

Tags: excel, date, if-statement, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet that tracks my personal finances and projects income + expenses for 2 pay periods following the current period.

I want the date cells for the pay periods to update automatically if I open the spreadsheet and `NOW()` is `>` the current period. Then I would like that to cascade down to the next 2 date fields, adding 14 days to each one (or perhaps choosing the next two dates in a pre-defined range).

At first I thought of a VLOOKUP table, but I can't figure out the 'logic' to it because a VLOOKUP compares one thing and returns another.

My latest idea was to do the following:

```
//Where C11 is the cell with the last pay date in it
//My other two cells simply reference C11 and add 14 and 28 days, respectively.
=IF(INT(NOW()) > INT(C11), C11=C11+14, C11)
```

This is returning `FALSE`, so something is obviously wrong as I have a condition for False set.

Comment: Note: INT(NOW()) can be more easily expressed with a single function - =TODAY()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update another cell from the formula of one cell.

For instance, you would put this formula in the two other cells referencing C11.

Since I have no visibility over your data, let's say the following:

- Cell A1 contains the current period
- Cell A2 contains the `IF` with `NOW()`: 
  `=IF((INT(NOW()) > INT(A1),"Update","Don't update")`.
- Cell A3 should contain another `IF` for the following 14 days after the current period;
   `=IF(A2 = "Update", A1+14, "")`.
- Cell A4 should contain yet another `IF` for the following 28 days after the current period;
   `=IF(A2 = "Update", A1+28, "")`.

Or you can put the `NOW()` in both cells A3 and A4... which means you don't need cell A2.

- Cell A1 contains the current period
- Cell A3 should contain another `IF` for the following 14 days after the current period;
   `=IF((INT(NOW()) > INT(A1), A1+14, "")`.
- Cell A4 should contain yet another `IF` for the following 28 days after the current period;
   `=IF((INT(NOW()) > INT(A1), A1+28, "")`.

Lastly, your currenty formula might be evaluating to `TRUE` and thus evaluates `C11=C11+14`. If C11 contains 12, it will become `12=12+14` which is false.

Comment: You're right, I was doing two things wrong: my statement was always evaluating to `False` because, as you said, 12 <> 12+14; I was also trying to affect other cells. I could make it work through VBA, but unfortunately I don't think macros work when you upload and convert to Google Drive. ;)

Comment: @armadadrive haha, that's okay. I saw that gDrive has a way to incorporate scripts. I'm not familiar with it myself, but there's a little tutorial on the documentation pages if you use the 'Help'. Worth a look if you want to use something like VBA there :)

Comment: Great! I'm not surprised that Google would have implemented some form of macro functionality. Thanks for the heads up, I will check it out. And thanks for taking the time to help me with my question.